# How we pass value of object reference in sendkeys

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using this

```
byte[] bytesDecode = Base64.decodeBase64(str.getBytes());
System.out.println("ecncoded value is " + new String(bytesDecode));

WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("locator value")).sendkeys(bytesDecode);
```

So, in this case how we pass the value of `bytesDecode` in send keys?

Comment: Use `new String(bytesDecode)` again.

Comment: @Guy can you give me an example how we use "new String(bytesDecode)" to enter value in webelement

Comment: by object reference you mean memory address of the string variable?

Comment: @santhoshkumar In a variable "bytesDecode" i stored my decode value and i want to pass this decode value in text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you have made two mistakes:

Issues with your program:

1. `WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("locator value")).sendkeys(bytesDecode);`

This is incorrect.It should be:

```
WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("locator value"));
```

2. You cannot pass bytesDecode directly. You have to change it to the character sequence before passing.
   It can be

   ```
    pass.sendKeys(new String(bytesDecode,"UTF-8"));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert bytecode to string by following code;

```
String str = new String(bytesDecode , "UTF-8");
```

And then pass that string in sendkays:

```
WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("locator value")).sendkeys(str);
```

Hope it will help you